# create multiple slider based on the chart by javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-ui

I am creating a quad tool through Javascript, I want create four sliders for each point I have on this quad tool.

The point on the chart is draggable now, I want to create slider for each of the point on the chart, once I slide the value to want I want, the points on the chart will change automatically. The slide range will based on the data I have in another file, use [0,100, 20] for now. I have the HTML format of the slider but the actual slider doesn't work. 
This is my slider part, I don't know it doesn't work 
http://jsfiddle.net/dz5q7Lg8/1

```
  function showValues() {
    $('#slider1').html(chart.options.chart.Series1);
    $('#slider2').html(chart.options.chart.Series2);
    $('#slider3').html(chart.options.chart.Series3);
    $('#slider4').html(chart.options.chart.Series4);
         }
//Activate the sliders

$('#slider1').on('change', function () {
    chart.options.chart.Series1 = this.value;
    showValues();
    chart.redraw(false);
});
$('#slider2').on('change', function () {
    chart.options.chart.Series2 = this.value;
    showValues();
    chart.redraw(false);
});
$('#slider3').on('change', function () {
    chart.options.chart.Series3 = this.value;
    showValues();
    chart.redraw(false);
});
$('#slider4').on('change', function () {
    chart.options.chart.Series4 = this.value;
    showValues();
    chart.redraw(false);
});

showValues();
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/dz5q7Lg8/1/

Comment: This is the JsFiddle link for my problem, Thanks.